# INSERT lots of records using SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I think i have cracked a way of generating the random numbers. But whats the best way in SQL server to loop this efficiently? 
I have the following SQL:

```
DECLARE @Random1 INT;
DECLARE @Random2 INT;
DECLARE @Random3 INT;
DECLARE @Random4 INT;
DECLARE @Random5 INT;
DECLARE @Random6 INT;

DECLARE @Upper INT;
DECLARE @Lower INT;

---- This will create a random number between 1 and 49
SET @Lower = 1 ---- The lowest random number
SET @Upper = 49 ---- The highest random number
SELECT @Random1 = ROUND(((@Upper - @Lower -1) * RAND() + @Lower), 0)
SELECT @Random2 = ROUND(((@Upper - @Lower -1) * RAND() + @Lower), 0)
SELECT @Random3 = ROUND(((@Upper - @Lower -1) * RAND() + @Lower), 0)
SELECT @Random4 = ROUND(((@Upper - @Lower -1) * RAND() + @Lower), 0)
SELECT @Random5 = ROUND(((@Upper - @Lower -1) * RAND() + @Lower), 0)
SELECT @Random6 = ROUND(((@Upper - @Lower -1) * RAND() + @Lower), 0)
--SELECT @Random;

INSERT INTO [lotto].[dbo].[CustomerSelections]
           ([draw_date]
           ,[val1]
           ,[val2]
           ,[val3]
           ,[val4]
           ,[val5]
           ,[val6])
     VALUES
           (
           '2013-07-05'
           ,@Random1
           ,@Random2
           ,@Random3
           ,@Random4
           ,@Random5
           ,@Random6 
           )
```

What is the best way to get SQL Server to run this SQL 100,000 times?

Comment: "Efficient" and "Loop" usually are not used in the same sentence when talking about SQL Server - RDBMSs are optimized for set operations. For 100K records, it may be more efficient to generate your data into a CSV file with an outside program, then use [`BULK INSERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) to load the table.

Comment: I use SQL Server to generate my random numbers. I cant generate outside of the server!

Comment: Did you try just looping.  It is still going to run pretty fast.  If you did 100 values each loop it would be faster.  And if you want to get fancy create the next set of randoms in another tread.  You do know .NET and most dev environments have random number generators.

Comment: I dont want to code C# just yet. Dont know enough :(... What loops could i use for SQL? im only young and still learning! :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Doing it all in one statement with no loops will be the most efficient way.

```
INSERT INTO [lotto].[dbo].[CustomerSelections]
           ([draw_date]
           ,[val1]
           ,[val2]
           ,[val3]
           ,[val4]
           ,[val5]
           ,[val6])
SELECT TOP (100000 )
           '2013-07-05',
           1 + ABS(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(8) % 49),
           1 + ABS(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(8) % 49),
           1 + ABS(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(8) % 49),
           1 + ABS(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(8) % 49),
           1 + ABS(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(8) % 49),
           1 + ABS(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(8) % 49)
FROM master..spt_values v1,
     master..spt_values v2
```

Answer (score 2):

This took 4 seconds:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @intFlag INT
SET @intFlag = 1
WHILE (@intFlag <=100000)
BEGIN

--Do Stuff
DECLARE @Random1 INT, @Random2 INT, @Random3 INT, @Random4 INT, @Random5 INT, @Random6 INT, @Upper INT, @Lower INT
---- This will create a random number between 1 and 49
SET @Lower = 1 ---- The lowest random number
SET @Upper = 49 ---- The highest random number
SELECT @Random1 = ROUND(((@Upper - @Lower -1) * RAND() + @Lower), 0)
SELECT @Random2 = ROUND(((@Upper - @Lower -1) * RAND() + @Lower), 0)
SELECT @Random3 = ROUND(((@Upper - @Lower -1) * RAND() + @Lower), 0)
SELECT @Random4 = ROUND(((@Upper - @Lower -1) * RAND() + @Lower), 0)
SELECT @Random5 = ROUND(((@Upper - @Lower -1) * RAND() + @Lower), 0)
SELECT @Random6 = ROUND(((@Upper - @Lower -1) * RAND() + @Lower), 0)
--SELECT @Random;

INSERT INTO #test  ([draw_date],[val1],[val2],[val3],[val4],[val5],[val6])
     VALUES ('2013-07-05',@Random1,@Random2,@Random3,@Random4,@Random5,@Random6)  

SET @intFlag = @intFlag + 1
END
GO
```

Update: This runs quickly because it is into a temp table, looping directly into actual table would be a much slower process, so you'd then want to INSERT the set into your final table from your temp table:

```
INSERT INTO Table
SELECT *
FROM #test
```

For reference, a simple WHILE loop shell:

```
DECLARE @intFlag INT
SET @intFlag = 1
WHILE (@intFlag <=5000)
BEGIN  
--Do Stuff

--Iterate
SET @intFlag = @intFlag + 1
END
GO
```

Comment: I would pull the declare and set out of the loop

Comment: @Blam agreed, just wanted to show OP logic inside of loop simply, might edit.

Comment: If you try inserting into a normal table in a user database rather than a `#temp` table pretty sure you will find this takes considerably longer than your first test. The 100,000 individual transaction commits will have a greater impact there.

Comment: @MartinSmith Good point, didn't clarify that in my answer, have updated now. Runs quickly into temp table, and inserting the full set from the temp table is quick as well.

Comment: Or a `BEGIN TRAN ... COMMIT` around the whole loop would also work. The reason that `#temp` tables perform better is because log pages in tempdb do not need to be flushed when a transaction is committed but in a user DB you would be potentially waiting for the log to be written 100,000 times. A set based insert will still be preferable though.