# Generate unique random numbers using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have some SQL code which generates random numbers using the following technique:

```
DECLARE @Random1 INT, @Random2 INT, @Random3 INT, @Random4 INT, @Random5 INT, @Random6 INT, @Upper INT, @Lower INT
---- This will create a random number between 1 and 49
SET @Lower = 1 ---- The lowest random number
SET @Upper = 49; ---- The highest random number


with nums as (
    select @lower as n
    union all
    select nums.n+1
    from nums
    where nums.n < @Upper
   ),
   randnums as 
   (select nums.n, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by newid()) as seqnum
    from nums
   )
select @Random1 = MAX(case when rn.seqnum = 1 then rn.n end),
       @Random2 = MAX(case when rn.seqnum = 2 then rn.n end),
       @Random3 = MAX(case when rn.seqnum = 3 then rn.n end),
       @Random4 = MAX(case when rn.seqnum = 4 then rn.n end),
       @Random5 = MAX(case when rn.seqnum = 5 then rn.n end),
       @Random6 = MAX(case when rn.seqnum = 6 then rn.n end)
from randnums rn;

select @Random1, @Random2, @Random3, @Random4, @Random5, @Random6
```

My question is how random is this number generation? and is there another way to do this which is more "random".

I am using:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP3) - 10.0.5512.0 (X64)   Aug 22 2012 19:25:47   Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
```

The problem with most solutions is you'll end up with values like this: `14,29,8,14,27,27` I cannot have duplicate numbers!

Comment: As in your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17413533/insert-lots-of-records-using-sql-server-2008) you could use `ORDER BY CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(8)` as that is documented to return a "cryptographic random number"

Comment: You are right, marked previous answer as ticked for your solution and up voted you on here. If you can explain how the code works in an answer here, ill mark you as ticked :)

Comment: Actually no, as you're method still causes dupes to show up: `
2,44,1,13,41,44`

Comment: The answer there doesn't meet the requirement here that there can be no repetition amongst the 6 numbers though. For that you can just take your existing query here and change the reference to `newid` to use `CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM` instead.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I guess you could do something like this much simpler and much easier

```sql
DECLARE @Upper INT;
DECLARE @Lower INT;
SET @Lower = 1;     /* -- The lowest random number */
SET @Upper = 49;    /* -- The highest random number */
    
    
SELECT @Lower + CONVERT(INT, (@Upper-@Lower+1)*RAND());
```

For getting a random number without repetition, this will do the job

```sql
WITH CTE 
AS
(
    SELECT  randomNumber, COUNT(1) countOfRandomNumber
    FROM (
    SELECT ABS(CAST(NEWID() AS binary(6)) %49) + 1 randomNumber
    FROM sysobjects
    ) sample
    GROUP BY randomNumber
)
SELECT TOP 5 randomNumber
FROM CTE
ORDER BY newid()
```

To set the highest limit, you can replace 49 with your highest limit number.

Comment: Well no, as i need to make sure the same number doesn't appear in random 1-6

Comment: The problem with this is that you'll end up with values like this: `14,29,8,14,27,27` I cannot have duplicate numbers!

Comment: @PriceCheaperton Have a look I have updated my answer, hopefully this will do the job

Comment: I don't see that this is any "more random" than what they already have. It still relies on the random properties of `newid`.

Comment: @MartinSmith My 1st suggestion could have duplicate random number but second suggestion will filter out all the duplicates and then select Random numbers from a Random selection in a random order, couldnt get any more random I guess :)

Comment: @MartinSmith I have never used or even heard of CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(8) looks like a good suggestion looking at it now on BOL thanks buddy :)

Comment: Simply assigning a random number to the numbers `1-49` and taking the top 6 (as they have in the OP) is fine. I don't see this adds any more randomness. My doubt is about the degree of randomness supplied by `newid` when compared to an inbuilt dedicated function such as `CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM`

Comment: @MartinSmith very good solution indeed. much simpler as well.

Answer (score 0):

For **Laravel**:

```
 public function generatUniqueId()
    {
        $rand = rand(10000, 99999);
        $itemId = $rand;
        while (true) {
            if (!BookItem::whereBookItemId($itemId)->exists()) {
                break;
            }
            $itemId = rand(10000, 99999);
        }

        return $itemId;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a list of random numbers. For this example I did 100, could be more, could be less (but no less than your limit)
2. Use row_number() function to detect duplicates
3. Once you delete the duplicates, select top 6 number in your list

   ```
    with RandomNumbers as
    (
        select id = 1, number = round(((56 - 1 -1) * RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) + 1), 0),
        orderid = round(((56 - 1 -1) * RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) + 1), 0)
        union all
        select id + 1, round(((56 - 1 -1) * RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) + 1), 0), round(((56 - 1 -1) * RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) + 1), 0) 
        from RandomNumbers where id < 100
    ), 
    NoDuplicates as
    (
        select number, id = row_number() over (partition by number orderid by order) from
        (
            select numeber, order, repeat = row_number() over (partition by numeber orderid by order)
            from RandomNumbers 
        ) a
        where repeat = 1
    )
   ```

   select * from NoDuplicates where id <= 6

Answer (score -2):

You can use Rand() function .

```
select CEILING(RAND() *<max of random numbers))
```