# pick random and unique items SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, random, unique

We are trying to populate a table with Random (and unqiue) values between 1-37.  The following query is not picking unique however.

```
truncate table [dbo].[webscrape]
declare @date date = '1990-01-01',
@endDate date = Getdate()

while @date<=@enddate
begin
insert into [dbo].[webscrape](date,value1,value2,value3,value4,value5)
SELECT @date date,convert(int,(RAND()*37-1+1)) value1,
convert(int,(RAND()*37-1+1)) value2,
convert(int,(RAND()*37-1+1)) value3,
convert(int,(RAND()*37-1+1)) value4,
convert(int,(RAND()*37-1+1)) value5

set @date = DATEADD(day,1,@date)
end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate unique random numbers using SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19875588/generate-unique-random-numbers-using-sql)

Answer (score 0):

If `value1`, `value2`, `value3`, `value4`, `value5` must be 5 unique random values from [1..37], then `insert` below might work:

```
;with ThirtySeven as (
    SELECT 1 As RowNum
    UNION ALL
    SELECT RowNum+1
        FROM ThirtySeven
        WHERE RowNum<37
), Randoms37 AS (
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [RowNum]) as RowNum,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID()) as Random
    FROM ThirtySeven
)
insert into [dbo].[webscrape](date,value1,value2,value3,value4,value5)
SELECT @date date, [1], [2], [3], [4], [5] 
from (select Random, RowNum from randoms37 where RowNum<=5) rnd37 
    pivot (min(random) FOR RowNum in ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5])) as rnd37
```

Answer (score 0):

The main point is creation table with available values and with picked values -when value is picked it deleted from  available and added to picked.

```
declare @initData table (ID int)
declare @pickedData table (ID int)
declare @i  int =0;
declare @pickAmount int = 7;
declare @pickedIndex int = 0;
declare @pickedValue int = 0;
set @i = 0;
while @i<37
begin
set @i = @i+1;
insert into @initData VALUES (@i)
end
while (select count(ID) from @pickedData) < @pickAmount
begin
 set @pickedIndex = convert(int,(RAND()*(select count(ID)-1 from @initData)))
 select @pickedValue=id from @initData order by id  OFFSET (@pickedIndex) ROWS FETCH NEXT (1) ROWS ONLY 
 insert into @pickedData VALUES (@pickedValue)
 delete from @initData where id = @pickedValue;
end
select * from @pickedData;
```