# Generate random number that does not exist

Tags: sql-server

Is there a simple way to generate a random number between `1` and `99999` that does not yet exist in the database?

I have a table called `Board` and one of the columns is `Number`.

I need to generate a new number randomly that does not yet exist as `Board.Number`.

Comment: Does it really need to be *random* or does it only need to be unique? A random number in a range of 100,000 is not very random overall, so I wonder why "random" is part of the requirement at all.

Comment: If you really just want "uniqe", use [IDENTITY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate unique random numbers using SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19875588/generate-unique-random-numbers-using-sql)

Comment: Will your table really 've only `99999` rows?

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach is the following statement (using a number table with `100000` rows and an appropriate join):

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Board ([Number] int)
INSERT INTO Board ([Number]) VALUES (1), (2), (4), (6008)
```

Statement:

```
;WITH TallyCTE AS (
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS [Number]
   FROM (VALUES (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) a(n)
   CROSS APPLY (VALUES (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) b(n)
   CROSS APPLY (VALUES (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) c(n)
   CROSS APPLY (VALUES (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) d(n)
   CROSS APPLY (VALUES (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) e(n)
)
SELECT TOP 1 t.[Number]
FROM TallyCte t
LEFT OUTER JOIN Board b ON b.[Number] = t.[Number]
WHERE (t.[Number] <= 99999) AND (b.[Number] IS NULL)
ORDER BY NEWID()
```